# How to get inner field's value of object by using JsonProperty

Tags: c#, json

I have data in json like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name" : "Car wash"
    "changed_by": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pascal",      
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
}
```

The value `"Car wash"` I can get like this:

```
public class Changes 
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

How I can get the value of some `changed_by` object field?

I need to use this in deserializing

```
private void GetChanges(RawData data)
{
    var changes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<IEnumerable<Model.Json.Changes>>>(data.ChangesData);
    /* some code */
}
```

Comment: You need to show complete code.

Comment: create a class representing `changed_by` node

Comment: You are accessing name _(Car wash)_ through `data` class/object. You need to access `changed_by` fields using `changed_by` class/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to have a class that represents the `changed_by` object. For example:

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ChangedBy changed_by { get; set; }
}

public class ChangedBy
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me!

Comment: Great, shame that someone else who downvoted me thought otherwise :)

Comment: this represents the data structure Alexey needs.  Looks Alexey's already using Json.Net, didn't see the edit soon enough.  Up voted you David!  Got a down vote too, don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class hierarchy representing the structure of the data in and then use Json.Net to deserialize it into an object of this class.

Check out [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)